Httpx requests timing out when it shouldn't
I have an asynchronous script that sends 1 request to different url (223 in this case) so not the same host. The problem is that after ~ 150 requests, it starts to timeout urls but when processing the timed out urls separately, it works fine and they get processed. I tried to use aiohttp and got the same results. I tried to add asyncio.sleep() and still the same problem. I tried to make one client per request and still the same results. I have no idea why it's getting timed out. Here's the function for requests :
async def fetch(url, client):
    headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36",  
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
}

    response = await client.get(url, follow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
    return response

and the running part :
urls_list = [site.strip() for site in start_urls.replace(',', ' ').split() if site.strip()]
if second_input:
    pattern_list = second_input
else:
    pattern_list = []
           
async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
    tasks = [process_url(url, skip_empty_results, depth, pattern_list, dataset, 5, client) for url in urls_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

fetch() is being used in process_url().

The asyncio.gather call, as it is in this code, will simply start all your 200 and a few requests concurrently - even if the URLs are different, if they are to the same service, they may throttle you (or even be overwhelmed).
( 223 simultaneous outgoing calls to different services should not slow down your system, but even that could happen, in case your network configuration is using a limited DNS service, for example).
Instead of gather you could try a coding pattern that will put, say, 50 calls at once, and replenish those after a while until you are done? It is possible to do so with asyncio.wait and a few variables to control the state. BTW, your snippet is missing the process_url function - I will assume it just call that fetch.
import asyncio


...


async def fetch(url, client):
    ...
    return response


async def process_url(*args):
    ...
    response = await fetch(...)
    ...


async def main():

    urls_list = [site.strip() for site in start_urls.replace(',', ' ').split() if site.strip()]
    if second_input:
        pattern_list = second_input
    else:
        pattern_list = []
            

    batch_size = 50 # roughly. to simplify the code, we will let these go up to this value * 1.33 
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = [process_url(url, skip_empty_results, depth, pattern_list, dataset, 5, client) for url in urls_list]
        current_tasks = set()
        done_tasks = set()
        while tasks or current_tasks:

            if tasks and len(current_tasks) < batch_size // 3:
                current_tasks.update(tasks[:batch_size])
                tasks[:batch_size] = []
                                    
            done, current_tasks = await asyncio.wait(current_tasks, timeout=10)
            done_tasks.update(done)

        results = [task.result() for task in in done_tasks if not task.exception()]
        # optionally handle tasks that raised an exception here
        ...


I did what you told to do. I get this error :
2024-04-13T16:30:45.032Z INFO  Exiting actor ({"exit_code": 0})
2024-04-13T16:30:45.188Z sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main.<locals>.process_url' was never awaited
2024-04-13T16:30:45.214Z RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback```

It is an issue with ReadTimeout in httpx.
Just disable read timeout and your old code will work fine.
Refer to this link.
